# Using Django Admin to create a ERP

Tags: python, erp

Very newbie question, but I need now before spend time learning a new language code.

Currently I develop some apps in C# on Desktop and I need starting migrate this apps to Web and I really like Django.

Can I use Django Admin to build an ERP? I can create complex web pages using master/detail?

Comment: You might want to check out existing Python based implementations for ERP, like ERPNext, etc.

Comment: Is ErpNext based in python?

Comment: @warpigs, we are thinking to about begins with a ERP using Django, our goal is ODOO, it is very complete but it's also expensive, if you want we can speak about that in private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That totally depends upon your project. Django Admin is highly useful for rapidly creating basic CRUDS for your database models.

You can go for some tweaks as documented here in the docs : [django admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/)

But when you need high level of customization, things become a little bit difficult because django admin is tightly coupled.

So you can go through the features and customization offered by django admin and decide for yourself.